# How to return an object in its derived type without converting back to base class type?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, type-conversion, components

First of all I'm really sorry for the title, but I have no idea how to phrase my question properly. Anyways, I was messing around with C++ and Allegro 5 creating the same game just using more complicated techniques for practice. Right now I'm trying to use entities and components but I've hit a snag.

```
this->entity = new Entity();

this->entity->addComponent(new ComponentTest());

// How I currently access components

ComponentTest *c = (ComponentTest*)this->entity->getComponent("test");
c->setVariable(10);

// This would be cool

this->entity->getComponent("test")->setVariable(10);

// This would be completely rad

this->entity["test"]->setVariable(10);
```

The problem is that Entity::getComponent returns a pointer to a Component so I have to explicitly cast it back to ComponentTest to be able to use its method ComponentTest::setVariable.

I was just wandering if there was some way to use the other two ways I mentioned for access. I'm also open to suggestions on some way to change the code to allow for easier access to components of an entity.

tl;dr: Too lazy to explicitly convert components. Is it possible to access components in the other two ways?

Comment: How about something like: `this->entity->getComponent<ComponentTest>("test")->setVariable(10);`

Comment: Also, for so many reasons under the sun. **Avoid** using C-style cast on polymorphic objects!

Comment: Kindly provide a [mcve]. A good example is having fake types like `Base`, `Derived` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a template function in Entity like this:

```
    template<typename T>
    T* getComponent(const std::string &componentName)
    {
        Component *component = getComponent(componentName);
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(component);
    }
```

And call it like @Jarod42 mentioned.